# Camera Rotate with Player Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a ball that move forward and bounce and rotate, and I want the camera to follow it and rotate with it so the camera always look at the ball from behind. So I made the script bellow but the camera didn't look at the ball when rotating!

> **NB:** I didn't use camera as a child of the ball because I don't want the camera to bounce.

**Camera Script:**

```
public Transform Ball;
private Vector3 Offset;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    Offset = transform.position - Ball.transform.position;

}

// Update is called once per frame
void LateUpdate () {

    transform.position = new Vector3(Ball.transform.position.x + Offset.x, transform.position.y, Ball.transform.position.z + Offset.z);
    transform.rotation = Ball.transform.rotation;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 [SerializeField]
 private Transform target;

 [SerializeField]
 private Vector3 offsetPosition;

 [SerializeField]
 private Space offsetPositionSpace = Space.Self;

 [SerializeField]
 private bool lookAt = true;

 private void Update()
 {
     Refresh();
 }

 public void Refresh()
 {
     if(target == null)
     {
         Debug.LogWarning("Missing target ref !", this);

         return;
     }

     // compute position
     if(offsetPositionSpace == Space.Self)
     {
         transform.position = target.TransformPoint(offsetPosition);
     }
     else
     {
         transform.position = target.position + offsetPosition;
     }

     // compute rotation
     if(lookAt)
     {
         transform.LookAt(target);
     }
     else
     {
         transform.rotation = target.rotation;
     }
 }
```

The target is your player gameobject

Comment: @Taik then create an update function and set the cameras y position to a specific value

Comment: Go into the inspector and look at the cams y position. In the cam script create an void Update() {} function and in that insert this line of code: gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(gameObject.transform.position.x, the float you read from the inspector, gameObject.transform.position.z);

Comment: Thank you so much!